# UnsatisfiedDependencyException when migrating spring project to 2.x

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to upgrade the spring boot project from 1.5.x to 2.1.3 
everything is compiled file but it gives run time exception

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'ldapParams'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapParams': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1395)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely one of the dependent beans needed by either `ldapConfig` or `ldapParams` beans has a prototype scope and a cyclic dependency (e.g. `ldapConfig` requires `ldapParams` but `ldapParams` requires `ldapConfig`). This results in new beans being created recursively until `StackOverflowError` is thrown.

Review your LDAP beans and remove cyclic dependency and prototype scope (if not needed).